# QOAuth error - qt creator - ‘QOAuth::Interface::Interface(const QOAuth::Interface&)’ is private

Tags: qt

```
/usr/include/QtOAuth/interface.h:101: error: ‘QOAuth::Interface::Interface(const QOAuth::Interface&)’ is private
```

Is the error I get. How to get around this? I've looked at the file `interface.h` and the method `Interface` is a public method.

Is there any reason why this would make an error?

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QByteArray token;
QByteArray tokenSecret;

QLabel *l = new QLabel("hello world");
QOAuth::Interface qoauth = new QOAuth::Interface;
qoauth->setConsumerKey( "key" );
qoauth->setConsumerSecret( "secret" );

qoauth->setRequestTimeout( 10000 );

QOAuth::ParamMap reply =
    qoauth->requestToken( "http://term.ie/oauth/example/request_token.php", QOAuth::GET, QOAuth::HMAC_SHA1 );

if ( qoauth->error() == QOAuth::NoError ) {
  token = reply.value( QOAuth::ParamToken );
  tokenSecret = reply.value( QOAuth::ParamTokenSecret );
  l->setText("Working");
}
else {
    l->setText("Not working");
}

l->show();

return a.exec();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to call the copy constructor of Interface which is not allowed (Q_DISABLE_COPY(Interface)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what you mean. I've put my code into my OP. Any chance you could have a look (I'm VERY new at Qt). :) thanks

Comment: I don't have QOAuth installed, so I cannot test this, but I think you need: QOAuth::Interface* qoauth = new QOAuth::Interface; [note the star]